# Matching two dataframes with texts

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataframe called df_profanity_en which contains a set of words. I have also another dataframe called df_ed with three columns (id, text, emotion_predicted).

I would like to create a new dataframe called df_filtered that contains only the texts of df_ed where words from the df_profanity_en are detected.

**I have implemented the following code, but as you can see the word assure shouln't be there. Any idea to solve this issue?**

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample df_profanity_en DataFrame
df_profanity_en = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['bad', 'offensive', 'curse', 'vulgar', 'ass']
})

# Create a sample df_ed DataFrame
df_ed = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'text': ['This is a clean text. Lets assure', 'There is a bad word here', 'No profanity in this one', 'Watch your language!', 'Another clean text'],
    'predicted_emotion': ['happy', 'sad', 'neutral', 'angry', 'happy']
})

# Create a list of profane words from df_profanity_en
profane_words = df_profanity_en['word'].tolist()

# Filter the texts in df_ed that contain profane words
df_filtered = df_ed[df_ed['text'].str.contains('|'.join(profane_words), case=False, na=False)]

# Add a new column containing the profanity word
df_filtered['profane_word'] = df_filtered['text'].apply(lambda text: next((word for word in profane_words if word.lower() in text.lower()), None))

# Optional: Reset the index if needed
df_filtered.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Print the filtered DataFrame
df_filtered
```

Output:

```
   id   text                                predicted_emotion      profane_word
    1   This is a clean text. Lets assure   happy                  ass
    2   There is a bad word here            sad                    bad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you have to add [*word boundaries*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to match the entire word :

```
pat = r"{}".format("|".join(r"\b{}\b".format(word) for word in df_profanity_en["word"]))
#'\\bbad\\b|\\boffensive\\b|\\bcurse\\b|\\bvulgar\\b|\\bass\\b'

m = df_ed["text"].str.contains(pat)

df_filtered = df_ed.loc[m]
```

Output :

```
print(df_filtered)

   id                      text predicted_emotion
1   2  There is a bad word here               sad
```

With [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to make the `profane_word` column :

```
df_filtered = (
    df_ed.assign(profane_word= df_ed["text"].str.extract(f"({pat})"))
            .dropna(subset="profane_word")
)
```

Another variant (with a clearer pattern), used by @[*mozway*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) :

```
import re

pat = fr"\b({'|'.join(map(re.escape, df_profanity_en["word"]))})\b"
#'\\b(bad|offensive|curse|vulgar|ass)\\b'

df_filtered = (
    df_ed.assign(profane_word= df_ed["text"].str.extract(pat))
            .dropna(subset="profane_word")
)
```

Output :

```
print(df_filtered)

   id                      text predicted_emotion profane_word
1   2  There is a bad word here               sad          bad
```

Comment: Oh, your answer didn't show until after I posted mine... Same logic ;)

Comment: What a coincidence.. thanks mozway ;) Btw, can I add/use your pattern format ? Because there is so much visible noise in mine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help both of you, your approach is really helpful!